# Unable to compile with my unit tests in C

Tags: c, makefile, c-criterion

I'm trying to compile my project with the Criterion framework for unit testing. Here's how my project is organized:

```bash
.
├── include
│   └── mysh.h
├── Makefile
├── obj
├── src
│   ├── arrays_handler.c
│   ├── builtin_env.c
│   ├── delete_from_env.c
│   ├── display_env.c
│   ├── display_prompt.c
│   ├── doubly_linked_list.c
│   ├── env_handler.c
│   ├── execute_command.c
│   ├── mysh.c
│   ├── my_strcmp.c
│   ├── my_strcpy.c
│   ├── my_strdup.c
│   ├── my_strlen.c
│   ├── my_strncmp.c
│   ├── my_strndup.c
│   ├── my_strrchr.c
│   ├── my_str_to_word_array.c
│   ├── name_slice.c
│   ├── parse_command.c
│   ├── sanitize.c
│   ├── shell_handler.c
│   └── strbind.c
└── tests
    ├── Makefile
    └── sanitize_test.c
```

To compile my project, I use a first Makefile (the one at the root), which works very well. Here are its contents:

```
INCLUDE_DIR :=  include
OBJ_DIR     :=  obj
SRC_DIR     :=  src
NAME        :=  mysh
CC          :=  gcc
CFLAGS      :=  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ggdb3
CPPFLAGS    :=  -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)

SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC_FILES))

all: $(NAME)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(NAME): $(OBJ_FILES)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    @$(MAKE) -C ./tests tests_clean
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o

fclean: clean
    @$(MAKE) -C ./tests tests_fclean
    @rm -rf $(NAME)

tests_run: fclean
    @$(MAKE) -C ./tests tests_run

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean tests_run re
```

The problem seems to lie with my second Makefile (in the test folder), which is unable to compile the `tests_run` rule. Here are its contents:

```
CC          :=  gcc
CFLAGS      :=  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ggdb3
CPPFLAGS    :=  -I../include
LDFLAGS     :=  -Lcriterion/lib
LDLIBS      :=  -lcriterion
NAME        = ../unit-tests
OBJ_DIR     = ../obj
SRC         = $(shell find ../src -name '*.c' ! -name 'mysh.c')
TEST_SRC    = $(shell find . -name '*.c')
OBJ         = $(patsubst ../src/%.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC))
TEST_OBJ    = $(patsubst ./%.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(TEST_SRC))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

tests_run: $(OBJ) $(TEST_OBJ)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(filter-out ../obj/mysh.o,$(TEST_SRC) $(SRC)) $(LDLIBS) -o $(NAME)
    @./$(NAME)

tests_clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJ)
    @rm -f ../*.gcda
    @rm -f ../*.gcno

tests_fclean: tests_clean
    @rm -f $(NAME)

.PHONY: tests_run tests_clean tests_fclean
```

I get the following error when calling `tests_run`:

```
make[1]: enter the "[...]/tests" directory
make[1]: exit the "[...]/tests" directory
make[1]: enter the "[...]/tests" directory
make[1]: exit the "[...]/tests" directory
make[1]: enter the "[...]/tests" directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target "../obj/display_prompt.o", required for "tests_run". Stop.
make[1]: exit directory "[...]/tests".
make: *** [Makefile:29: tests_run] Error 2
```

Can you help me correct this Makefile?

Comment: To begin, stop suppressing output from the recipes in your second Makefile.  If you ever suppress your recipes' output at all, you should defer until the makefile is fully working.  Otherwise, you're throwing away information that is important for debugging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error ...

> ```
> make[1]: *** No rule to make target "../obj/display_prompt.o", required for "tests_run". Stop.
> ```

... is emitted when `make` is processing your second makefile, but it is *about* `../obj/display_prompt.o`, which is the responsibility of your *first* makefile.  One of the [drawbacks of recursive `make`](https://accu.org/journals/overload/14/71/miller_2004/), such as you are using, is that the separate `make` runs are largely independent.  There are ways for them to communicate, but they do not share rules or dependency information, so although the top-level makefile knows how to build `obj/display_prompt.o` (relative to its own directory), the second level makefile does not know how build the same file, which for it is `../obj/display_prompt.o`.

The second-level makefile needs all the main object files, so if you want this recursive `make` arrangement to work then the top level makefile needs to ensure that they are built before recursing to the second-level makefile.  But it doesn't.  In fact, it does the exact opposite.  The top-level `tests_run` target has `fclean` as a prerequisite, which in turn has `clean` as a prereq, which unconditionally deletes all the object files.

#### Preliminary

I see no reason at all for the top-level `tests_run` target to delete the object files.  It is counter-productive.  Perhaps your idea is to perform a clean build of these files for the tests, but if your makefile correctly captures all their dependencies then that should not be necessary.  Moreover, if ever you do want to perform a clean build before testing then you can request it easily enough: `make fclean; make tests_run`.

Additionally, your second-level makefile should have a separate rule for building the `unit-tests` executable.  That build should not be buried in a recipe for running the same.

#### Solution 1

If you continue with the recursive `make` approach, then instead of removing the object files, the top-level `tests_run` rule must ensure, directly or indirectly, that they are built. That might look like this:

```
tests_run: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(MAKE) -C ./tests tests_run
```

#### Solution 2

I'm not a big fan of recursive `make`, though I do use it in certain situations.  Here, though, I would use a single makefile, non-recursively, to build everything.  If you want, you can keep it somewhat modular by redesigning the second-level Makefile to be `include`d by the top-level one, maybe something like this:

```
TESTS_LDFLAGS     :=  -Ltests/criterion/lib
TESTS_LDLIBS      :=  -lcriterion
TESTS_NAME   = unit-tests
TESTS_SRC    = $(shell find tests -name '*.c')
TESTS_OBJ    = $(patsubst tests/%.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(TESTS_SRC))

$(TESTS_NAME): $(filter-out $(OBD_DIR)/mysh.o,$(OBJ)) $(TESTS_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(TESTS_LDFLAGS) $(TESTS_LDLIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: tests/%.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

tests_run: $(TESTS_NAME)
    ./$(TESTS_NAME)

tests_clean:
    rm -rf $(TEST_OBJ)
    rm -f *.gcda
    rm -f *.gcno

tests_fclean: tests_clean
    rm -f $(TEST_NAME)

.PHONY: tests_run tests_clean tests_fclean
```

In the top-level makefile, you would want to remove `run_tests` rule (`tests_run` will instead be used directly), and add `include tests Makefile` somewhere near the end.  (Though if it were me, I would also rename the second-level file to `tests.mk` or similar, to clarify that it is not (any longer) a standalone makefile.

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
```

Tells make, "if you want to build a file `../obj/X.o` you can create it from a file `X.c`".

Then you ask make to build a file `../obj/display_prompt.o`, so make looks for a file `display_prompt.c`.  However, that file doesn't exist.  There is a source file `../src/display_prompt.c` but that's not the file you told make could be used, so it doesn't look for that file.

There are various ways to do this.  One way is do add a new rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: ../src/%.c
        ...
```

Now make knows how to build an object file from source files in `../src` as well as in the local directory.

Or, you can assume that someone else (the main makefile) already created the object files and this makefile doesn't need to build them: in that case take the object files out of the prerequisites list and just put them in the link line:

```
tests_run: $(NAME)
        ./$(NAME)

$(NAME): $(TEST_OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

(it's wrong to have your target depend on the object files then add the source files to the link line... why do that?  it will recompile all the files again!)

You could also use VPATH to find the source files.  Personally I think the second option is the best.  It's always problematic to have two different makefiles containing rules to build the same object files.